# What is the inverse Laplace Transformation for $\exp (a s^4)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, proof-writing, laplace-transform

I need to find the inverse Laplace transform for $$ \exp(a\cdot s^4) $$ where a is a constant.

Alternatively, I need to calculate the following integral:
$$f(t)=
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\alpha -i\infty }^{\alpha +i\infty }e^{
as^{4}+ts} ds $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Because $s\mapsto \exp(as^4)$ is entire, the inverse Laplace transform is just $$\int\limits_{-\mathrm i \infty}^{+\mathrm i \infty}\mathrm e^{st}\exp(as^4)\mathrm ds$$.

Comment: Dear K.defaoite. My question is part of a long boundary value problem I try to solve and there is no need to insert information that does not important for the reader

Comment: Can one make any assumptions on the constant $a$ (e.g. $a<0$)?

Comment: The comment by user @K.defaoite is useful because I believe it illustrates the integral can be evaluated as a Fourier transform (or inverse Fourier transform) with the variable substitution $s=i z$. Mathematica gives a result for $\Re(a)<0$ if you're interested.

Comment: @Amr You said you wanted to calculate the inverse transform, and when I tell you how to do it, you say it's "not important"? okay...

Answer (score 0):

Use Taylor expansion as follows:
\begin{equation*}
e^{as^{4}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{a^{n}}{n!}s^{4n}
\end{equation*}

Apply inverse Laplace transform for two sides, then
\begin{equation*}
L^{-1}\left( \mathbf{e}^{as^{4}}\right)
=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{a^{n}}{n!}L^{-1}\left(
s^{4n}\right) 
\end{equation*}
use the following relation
\begin{equation*}
L^{-1}\left( s^{n-1}\right) =\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}\delta
\left( t\right) ,\qquad n=1,2,...
\end{equation*}
use
\begin{equation*}
n=4k+1,\qquad k=0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation*}
therefore, we have
\begin{equation*}
L^{-1}\left( \mathbf{e}^{as^{4}}\right)
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{a^{4k+1}}{\left( 4k+1\right) !}\frac{d^{4k}%
}{dt^{4k}}\delta \left( t\right) ,\qquad k=0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation*}

Comment: I don't understand your answer since $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[s^{n-1}\right](t)=\frac{t^{-n}}{\Gamma (1-n)}$ and $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[s^{4 n}\right](t)=\frac{t^{-4 n-1}}{\Gamma (-4 n)}$. Is $\delta(t)$ the Dirac Delta function?

Comment: Dear Steven,
Could you provide me with the reference for your formula? My formula contains the Dirac Delta function. Also, we can check the reference Debnath L, Bhatta D. Integral Transforms and Their Applications. 2014. https://doi.org/10.1201/b17670. Page 650

Comment: Dear Steven, I think that your formula is valid for n less than or equal 1

Comment: I believe
$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{a^n}{n!} \frac{\partial^{4 n}\,\delta (t)}{\partial t^{4 n}}\right](s)=\frac{a^n}{n!} s^{4 n}\tag{1}$$
so it seems to me
$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[e^{-a s^4}\right](t)
=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!} \frac{\partial^{4 n}\,\delta (t)}{\partial t^{4 n}}\tag{2}$$
which seems inconsistent with your result.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=InverseLaplaceTransform%5Bs%5E%284n%29%2Cs%2Ct%5D) indicates the inverse Laplace transform of $s^{4n}$ is
$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[s^{4 n}\right](t)=\frac{t^{-4 n-1}}{\Gamma (-4 n)}\tag{3}$$
but [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=LaplaceTransform%5Bt%5E%28-4+n+-+1%29%2FGamma%5B-4n%5D%2C+t%2C+s%5D) indicates the corresponding Laplace transform of $\frac{t^{-4 n-1}}{\Gamma (-4 n)}$ is
$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{t^{-4 n-1}}{\Gamma(-4 n)}\right](s)=s^{4 n}\tag{4}$$
is only valid for $\Re(n)<0$.